# Filter out files matching a pattern in bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, pattern-matching

I have the following list of file names (strings) in `bash`

`"foo_file1.yaml" "file2.yaml" "anotherfile.yaml"`

I want to filter out files matching the pattern `foo*.yaml`

The following test does not seem to work:

```bash
for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
  if [[ $file == foo*.yaml ]]; then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

`steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files` contains the aforementioned list.

(it is from a step in a GHA job but I don't think this is relevant)

Any suggestions?

**edit**: I have also tried this

```
echo $file | grep -e 'foo*\.yaml'
```

still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the list of file names really include a comma between them? If you remove that, the code does what I think you hope it should do. Demo: https://ideone.com/GaYpJA

Comment: The `grep` looks for any line which matches, but your regex is wrong. Try `printf '%s\n' ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }} | grep 'foo.*\.yaml'` where the `printf` splits the list into individual lines.

Comment: Τhe following does not seem to work either `file=foo_bar.yaml` `if [[ $file == 'foo*.yaml' ]]; then echo "Fi"; fi ` (prints nothing)

Comment: Because you added gratuitous single quotes around the pattern.

Comment: `echo $file | grep -o 'foo.*.yaml'`

Comment: Missing a `done` to close the `for loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **grep**, you don't need to actually check the condition. Something like this should work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in "foo_file1.yaml" "file2.yaml" "anotherfile.yaml"; do
 echo $file | grep -o 'foo.*.yaml'
done
```

It outputs:

```bash
foo_file1.yaml
```

Comment: The question had a given input of `[ foo_file1.yaml, file2.yaml, anotherfile.yaml ]` so I'm not sure how this answer addresses the question...

Comment: @miken32 it worked for the person who asked the question so I guess the answer addresses the question very well!